# Replace Dataframe value in row with the value of the row below

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following frame

```
+-------+--------+-----+--+
|   1   |   2    |  3  |  |
+-------+--------+-----+--+
| hi    | banana | 123 |  |
|       | apple  |     |  |
| hello | pear   | 456 |  |
|       | orange |     |  |
+-------+--------+-----+--+
```

What is the most pythonic way of replacing the value in column 2 for each odd row with the value from the row below, i.e. having a df like

```
+-------+--------+-----+
|   1   |   2    |  3  |
+-------+--------+-----+
| hi    | apple | 123 |
| hello | orange | 456 |
+-------+--------+-----+
```

Comment: `df.ffill().drop_duplicates(keep='last')` ? for specific columns you can take a subset of the dataframe instead of the whole df

Comment: @anky or `df.replace("", np.nan, regex=True).ffill().iloc[1::2]`

Comment: @Manakin right,if they are spaces,  just noticed the `drop_duplicates` command in my comment should also have a subset of the 1st column may be

Comment: @anky not for us to decide business logic ;)

Comment: I meant for solution in my comment